# MarkLogic GeoSpatial Query returns no score

Tags: geospatial, marklogic

I understand geospatial queries by default do not add to a score, but I am finding they still don't when the appropriate options are added:

```
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs');  
jsearch.documents()   
        .where(
                 cts.jsonPropertyGeospatialQuery("coordinates",
                 cts.circle(45,cts.point(-28.81354,153.2773)),
                  ["score-function=reciprocal", "slope-factor=10.0","type=long-lat-point","units=km"]
                     ,1.0)


         )
        .slice(0,100)       
      .map({snippet: true})
      .result()
```

Returns the following

```
{
   "results": [
      {
        "uri": "/A/URI/5797f1514689edaf278d2f9e.json", 
         "index": 0, 
         "matches": [
               {
"path": "fn:doc(\"/A/URI/5797f1514689edaf278d2f9e.json\")/object-node()", 
      "matchText": [
           ..."


       ]
}, ...
```

No Score included.

Can anyone explain why no score or how I can get one?

Please see workspace attached. It is a alteration from the geospatial tutorial.
I have the following question on it.

Can anyone explain why only **cts.search** reduces the return set to one matching record?

**cts.uris** returns all that have the field coords but does not reduce these to the documents that are inside the circle. If the queries are by default unfiltered  why pass a query at all?

jsearch returns the same as cts.uris and I can live with this BUT why are all scores 0  one should be exactly at the centre of the circle.

[Workspace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aytqci9m3pfwb7i/ML9_Geospatial_Search%20%281%29.xml?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up, as the question has been updated since my original answer. The workspace was helpful in understanding what was going on.

You are creating a **Geospatial Path Index** on on `/location/coords` but are using [cts.jsonPropertyGeospatialQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyGeospatialQuery), which cannot take advantage of that index. Without an appropriate backing index for your geospatial query criteria, you will need to rely on filtering.

Instead, you should be using [cts.pathGeospatialQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.pathGeospatialQuery), so that it can leverage the geospatial index to provide a fast and accurate *unfiltered* result, rather than having to rely on filtering.

```
cts.pathGeospatialQuery("/location/coords", circle, ['units=km'], 1.0)
```

---

As for why the `score` was not being returned in the result of the search, it appears that the reason why the score is not being returned, is because the incorrect option `type=long-lat-point` is specified. The indexed values are `type=point`

When I either specify `type=point` or remove the type option, a non-zero score is returned.

---

When applying `.map({snippet: true})`, the jsearch implementation will only include those properties when their values are present and are not equal to `0`.

If you remove `.map({snippet: true})` you will see the `score`, `confidence`, and `fitness` in the result.

If you find that they are indeed missing or are equal to `0` and you still want those properties to be present in your results, you could conditionally add them in after the fact:

```
const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs');  
let result = jsearch.documents()   
        .where(
          cts.jsonPropertyGeospatialQuery("coordinates",
             cts.circle(45,cts.point(-28.81354,153.2773)),
             ["score-function=reciprocal", "slope-factor=10.0","type=long-lat-point","units=km"],
             1.0)
         )  
        .slice(0,100)  
        .map({snippet: true})
        .result();

result.results.forEach(r => ["score","fitness","confidence"].forEach(p => r[p] ? null : r[p]=0));

result;
```

Comment: Yet I know data matches the query. In fact one of the records is the centre of the circle. I would expect to see a score not 0

Comment: Verify that the `type` option is correct for the points that you are querying, as well as the appropriate index and query combinations to allow for accurate index-resolved results with scores.

Comment: Why this comment? "If you remove .map({snippet: true}) you will see the score, confidence, and fitness in the result. I suspect you will find that they are all equal to 0."

Comment: That was in my original response when looking to diagnose the issue, and a way to help troubleshoot. Removing the snippet option helps see what the score being returned is. If there is no score or value is zero, and snippet is applied, then that property is dropped from result output.

Comment: I was working with the documents and indexes created in the workspace linked in the question, and was able to get scores in the output. If you are working with a different set of data and indexes, the query may need adjustment, but it is difficult to tell how unless you can provide information or a similar workspace. Can you verify the correct results when executing against the data and indexes from the workspace in the question?